# Does loga/logb = log(a^(1/logb))?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$.

However, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28a%5E%281%2Flog%28b%29%29%29%20-%20%28loga%2Flogb%29&a=*FunClash.log-_*Log10-) tells me that $\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$ does not equal $\log(a^\frac{1}{\log(b)})$.

Is Wolfram Alpha correct? If it is, why is it correct?

I'm using base 10 logs instead of natural logs, although I doubt it makes a difference.

Comment: try this  : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%5Clog%28a%5E%281%2Flog%28b%29%29%29+%3D+%28loga%2Flogb%29+over+reals

Comment: On your link, it seems that the values of the differences are very small. I would then say that it is just an approximation problem.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore. Point made elsewhere (edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are correct.

However, you must take note that there are some constraints (which are pretty self-explanatory).

$$\log(a^{\left(\frac{1}{\log(b)}\right)}) = \frac{\log a}{\log b}$$

As long as,

$$a > 0, \text{because you cannot take the logarithm of a negative number or 0}$$
$$b \ne 1\ \text{and}\ b >0, \text{because then} \log{b} = 0, \text{which means that the fraction} \frac{1}{\log b} \text{would be undefined}$$

Hope this helps you understand why.

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Do you mean $b\neq1$? And $b > 0$. I'm still not sure why Wolfram Alpha says its not equals though.

Comment: @umopaplsdn yes as you can see I fixed it. do you see why you are correct now? I think the error was in Wolfram-Alpha and approximations

Comment: If the asker is correct & what he's inputted into Wolfram is $0$ then why is the plot not zero? It's quite bumpy in fact. Do you think this is just due to approximation errors?

Comment: @EulCan it must be. I think its the only logical explanation. The two logarithms are equal as long as the given constraints I stated are not broken.

Comment: @VarunIyer Either that or Wolfram's coded wrong (impossible!).

Comment: @EulCan One thing is for sure, OP is not wrong.

Comment: Coded wrong? Are you crazy?

Nevertheless, I think I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @umopaplsdn no problem. Never admit you're wrong, even if a computational engine says so :).

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might be that $\log(x)$ is a multivalued function if you allow complex outputs. This is due to the fact that $e^{2\pi i n}=1$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The complex logarithm can give out different values as follows.

$$\log(z)=\ln|\,z\,|+i\arg(z+2\pi n)$$

So when you take one value for the left hand side of your original equation, you could take a completely different one for the right hand side (though I'm not entirely certain that this is the reason).